# How to split a filename at a specified delimiter

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have around 200 filenames that I am trying to pull data from. The format is something along the lines of: filename(120516.1108).mp3 I am trying to pull the part before the "("  and also the part before the ".". Not all of the files have this format either so theres an extra challenge.

The output should be : "filename"  "120516"

I am wanting to perform this operation in bash if at all possible. I am still learning and have very little experience in bash. Any explanations along with code is very welcome.

Comment: To clarify the question please add what the output should be at your example.

Comment: Added an example of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly that command should work(if there are no '(' and '.' In the filename)

```
data=$(echo $file | cut -d"." -f1 | tr -d "(")
```

Split them into 2 variables:

```
filename=$(echo $file | cut -d"(" -f1)
number=$(echo $file | cut -d"(" -f2 | cut -d"." -f1)
```

Comment: When ran I received a missing operand error: tr: missing operand after ‘(’
Two strings must be given when translating.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the -d for delete after tr

Comment: It works! Is there any way to split the result into two different data segments?

Comment: Like what? Describe/Give an example

Comment: Split the "filename" and "120516" into two different variables. Like f = "filename" and d = "120516" ?

Comment: Look at the edit

Comment: This is fragile. It breaks on file names containing spaces or other less common characters.

Answer (score 3):

"in bash", something like:

```
re='^(.*)\(([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+\).*$'
```

Then

```
for f in *.mp3; do 
  [[ $f =~ $re ]] && printf '"%s" "%s"\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) truncation.

```
case "$filename" in
  *\(*.*\)*)
    before_first_parenthesis=${filename%%\(*}
    after_first_parenthesis=${filename#*\(}
    before_dot=${after_first_parenthesis%%.*}
    echo "$before_first_parenthesis" "$before_dot"
  *) echo "does not match the format";;
esac
```